# JavaScript insert script with async and use functions from it?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have written a small widget which I include onto pages like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _sid = '1';
  (function() {
    var se = document.createElement('script'); se.type = 'text/javascript'; se.async = true;
    se.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://') + 'dev.domain.com/widget/hello.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(se, s);
  })();  
</script>
```

Now I want to find a way to call functions that exist within `hello.js`, which currently looks like this:

```
var widget = function () {

    function setName(a) {
        console.log(a);
    }

    return widget;  
}();
```

So I want to be able to make a call to setName like so: `widget.setName("Andy")`

...from the embed page, but for some reason I get "widget is undefined."

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Alosyius does this relate in any way to jquery - don't just approve edit's but take a closer look and reject them if they don't make any sense! BtT: since you load your script asynchronous, you have to check first, if it has already finished loading.

Comment: I dont want to use any jquery at all :)

Comment: You don't attach a load event handler to the script. When the load event handler runs, the script is fully available and you can call the functions defined in the script.

Comment: I dont want to have to change the embed code

Comment: You'll have to change the embed code, it's the only way to guarantee that the module has completed loading.

Comment: If you don't add a load event handler, you won't be able to know when the script was loaded and call a function from the script. It's as simple as that. If you don't want to change how you embed the script, fine. But then you cannot do what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you use widget, you need to know it is loaded, there are multiple options for that:

1. Use requireJs or something like it.
2. Implement a callback function in the javascript you are loading, say it will fire 'document.onHelloIsLoaded', then if you want to know if hello is loaded, just set that variable to a function.
3. Make a loop, checking if the widget variable is set. setInterval (which cancels itself when widget is found and the code has executed)

you also need to make the setName variable accessible when you have access to widget, which it now isn't. You should put something like this:

```
var widget = {};
widget.setName = function()... 
return widget;
```

Comment: How would i implement a callback function? That sounds like the best option

Comment: option 3 is probably not a good idea. Use `onload` or in IE `readystatechange` and pass a callback handler.

Comment: *"You can use while [...]"* No you can't. That would block the browser since JavaScript is single-threaded.

Comment: @Felix I know it would block, but you CAN. It is not async anymore and that is why I put it in option 3,and not option 1. (I also think that is a really bad idea, but I was just giving all possible solutions I know)

Comment: @Alosyius you have to change the embed code for that, and I just read you prefer not to.  I recommend requireJS, because that will just handle it for you on a way that many people use (I don't know if you need to change the embed code for requireJS though)

Comment: How would i change the embed code to make the callback solution work? I think the callback would be the best option after all

Comment: The strange thing is my embed code is exactly the same as Google Analytics, and for some reason i can access the Google analytics code like i would want

Comment: How would the code look like? `while(!window.widget){}` and wait until the loaded code runs to set `window.widget`? As I said, this won't work because the code of the loaded would never run since the browser is blocked by the `while` loop. It shouldn't be in the list of solutions at all because it is *not* a solution.

Comment: @Alosyius: I don't know what GA code you are using exactly, but I assume it's something like `var _gaq = _gaq || []; _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-Y']); ...`. Notice the first part: `var _gaq = _gaq || []`. If `_gaq` is not defined, you initialize it explicitly with an array. I.e. you don't wait until GA code is loaded, you simple create your own data structure. The difference is that once GA is loaded, it will look whether `_gaq` exists and the executes the commands it contains.

Comment: Ah i see, could i do something like _gaq instead then?

Comment: @Alosyius: Since you control the code, sure.

Comment: @Felix Kling: Didn't think of the loop blocking the inclusion, that is smart! Thanks! :)